# if statement does not work with fraction, but works with decimal equivalent

Tags: programming, c++, sketch, loop

I'm trying to trouble shoot a problem with my code and narrowed it down to my if statement not working with a fraction.

The below code does not work and returns 0

```
for(float i=0; i <= 1; i += .0001){
 t += .0001;
 if(t >= 1/440){ //Fraction
   t = 0;
 }
 Serial.println(t*100);
 delay(100);
}
```

But when I replace the 1/440 with its decimal equivalent (.0022727) it works fine and counts from 0 to 2.2

```
for(float i=0; i <= 1; i += .0001){
 t += .0001;
 if(t >= 0.0022727){ //Decimal
   t = 0;
 }
 Serial.println(t*100);
 delay(100);
}
```

If there is a simple way to use a fractional value instead of a decimal value it would make my application much similar.
Thanks.

Comment: Always present float calculations like this 1.0/440.0 and not 1/440 to prevent  these being treated as integer calculations. Avoid using floats in comparisons especially '==' comparisons.

Comment: @6v6gt  Please read [When shouldn't I comment?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If you aren't requesting clarification from the author (or the other couple of reasons to comment on the question) then you **should be posting an answer** instead.

Comment: @6v6gt You may want to look at [this](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/trivial-questions-must-be-off-topic). I don't know if it will matter being as old as it is, but you could weigh in on it if you have the interest; I don't. But I would them to make up their minds about it.

Comment: @NickGammon One problem with giving a formal answer in such a borderline off topic case (this one could fail if the often applied test "non-Arduino specific" is applied and it does anyway have a general C/C++ look to it) is that the answerer risks losing a couple of Brownie points if someone decides to assert that it is off topic and starts down-voting both the question and the answer.  Some answers which I have put considerable effort into, and the OP could not have known that the solution to the problem was "Non-Arduino specific", have ended up with a -1 score.

Comment: @6v6gt Yeah, I agree. I try to ignore the occasional down-vote as there are people who like to nitpick that sort of stuff. It's true it's really a programming question, but we do have a `programming` tag after all, so I think programming questions are OK. Especially if beginners to Arduino maybe think that the Arduino has different rules to C++.

Comment: "[The process of designing and writing source code as part of a program (or sketch) for Arduino.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming)" It is not clear that this applies to the question asked nor the answer given. Nor that it isn't in conflict with "[If the solution would be the same with or without Arduino, then it's usually a general coding question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". I don't disagree with your desire to answer it here. But your thinking is not _evidently_ supported by the rules where it isn't evidently _not_ supported by the rules.

Answer (score 2):

`1/440` will be treated as an integer expression, returning zero.

To make it work, make one or both operands a floating-point type. In your case:

```
 if(t >= (float)1 / 440){ //Fraction
   t = 0;
 }
```

Or:

```
 if(t >= 1.0/440){ //Fraction
   t = 0;
 }
```